# Excel: Sum if value if there's a 1 in a cell and two cells match

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table.

The left-most column lists a bunch of items.

The top-most row lists a bunch of years.

The cells at the intersection show if these items were present on a given year.

For instance:

```
              1999     1998     1997     1996   
Red             1        1        0        0
Blue            0        0        1        0
Red             1        0        1        0
Blue            1        1        1        1
```

Basically what I want to do is sum the number of the same item in a year. For  instance in the example above I will get a sum of 2 reds and 1 blue for 1999.

Is there anyway to set excel to say sum(B2-B400) if b1= b500.

Here I'm assuming At b500 I have the overall list of values whilst B1-400 lists the items

Comment: I think you can use SUMIFS function if you are using Excel 2007 or above.

Comment: SUMIF or SUMIFS is what you need. If you provide real sample data then we should be able to answer with a formula which works.

Comment: since the values are 1 and 0 you could use `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your given example I think this is the code you want to put in your total cell:

For the reds this will be: `=SUMIF($A:$A; "red"; B:B)`
For the blues this will be: `=SUMIF($A:$A; "blue"; B:B)`
I made this `$` sign so that when you put the formula in B6 you can drag the formula to C5, D5, and-so-on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can let Excel do the heavy lifting to summarize data like this.  There is a built-in wizard called a pivot table.

[image]

I created the pivot table starting in G1 with a few mouse clicks.  Note that I added a column title for column A to give it a name to work with.  The basic steps:

- Highlight the data.
- In the menu or toolbar, Insert Pivot Table.  You will have an option for where to locate the pivot table; I told it to start in G1.
- You will see a list of the different fields (column names), that are available.
- Drag Item to the Rows window.
- Drag each of the years to the Values window.  There are options for what type of aggregation you want for each of the columns.  The default is Sum, which is what you want for this.
- By default, it may show a grand total for the columns and/or rows.  You can right-click on that and remove it (or deselect it in the settings).

And you're done.  No brain cells were strained in using this wizard.  :-)